Do superluminal shadows drop the local temperature on distant objects?
There are lots of examples online of the scenario of someone with sufficient machinery casting a shadow of their thumb on the moon.  It's argued the shadow travels faster than light, instantaneously even, 'from one's thumb to the surface of the moon' but that this is not the transmission of information.  I understand that I can't transmit morse code with a shadow to the moon, because the alternating light would need to travel at light speed, and I also understand that I can't locally cause information to move around between different locations on the moon. But surely the faster than light shadow is some sort of causal influence since the shadow would cause,  even if ever so slightly, the temperature to drop wherever it's cast?  If I told a lunar being beforehand that if it gets cast in shadow, that means bombs are coming his way, certainly that is some sort of superluminal one-way information is occurring?

Stand up and spin around in a circle such that you return to your original position in one second. In a frame of reference fixed to your head the moon just traveled in a circular path of distance about 1.5M miles. So... the moon seemingly traveled at 1.5 million miles per second in the frame fixed to your head, which is almost ten times the speed of light! Does this violate the postulates of relativity or causality? No. It does not.

It's argued the shadow travels faster than light, instantaneously even No it isn't.

This is a great example of an XY problem. The X question that’s emerged is about heat transfer in shadows. The original Y problem is a misunderstanding of what is and isn’t superluminal information transfer. Two things  occurring in rapid succession with large spacing doesn’t  constitute superluminal information transfer when the first doesn’t directly influence the second.

There is no contradiction here.  The moon is about one light-second away.  If you move your thumb in front of a light source, a person on the moon will see the light wink out about one second later.  During that time, the person on the moon receives all of the photons that were emitted during the second before you moved your thumb.

It's argued the shadow travels faster than light, instantaneously even, 'from one's thumb to the surface of the moon' but that this is not the transmission of information.

With respect: nobody who knows what they're talking about argues this.  What you many be thinking of is the argument that if you move your thumb from left to right across a light sources, the shadow can move across the moon's surface faster than light.  However, this "movement of a shadow" is not a causal influence; it cannot be used to transmit information between two people on the surface of the moon.

Ok I think I understand the non-instantaneous shadow, that there's a delay of continuing photons before the lunar  area is in darkness.  But what about the colder temperatures in the shadow I mentioned?  Imagine in the extreme that the difference between being in light or in shadow was the difference of millions of degrees... wouldn't that result in a causal 'death shadow' path that I, the earthling, could cause to happen on and across the moon, faster than light?  Wouldn't that qualify as causal influence, even if not information transfer?

@Svenn:  The temperature stays at a fixed level because there is an equilibrium between the photon energy going in and the photon energy being radiated away.  In that one second between when you block the light and when the moon sees the shadow, the rate at which photons are arriving remains the same.  So the equilibrium temperature remains the same until the photons stop arriving one second later.

@Svenn The shadow can travel across the Moon faster than light, but it takes one second or so for the shadow to arrive at the Moon.
